# GetCurrentDirectory() is breaking the code in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

In the following code if I comment out the call to "GetCurrentDirectory" everything works fine, but if I don't then the code breaks after it, no child windows show up, but the program don't crash. The compiler doesn't give any error.

```
 char *iniFilePath;
 int lenWritten = GetCurrentDirectory( MAX_PATH, iniFilePath );
 if( lenWritten )
 {
     lstrcat( iniFilePath, iniFileName.c_str() );
     char *buffer;
     GetPrivateProfileString( iniServerSectionName.c_str(), serverIp.c_str(), "", buffer, MAX_PATH, iniFilePath );// server ip
     MessageBox( 0, buffer, 0, 0 );
 }
 else
 {
     MessageBox( 0,0,0,0 );
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using `GetPrivateProfileString` anyway? The reference says it's only for compatibility with 16-bit applications, most of which should be long gone now.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar because it is easy to use....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`iniFilePath` is an unintialised pointer which [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is attempting to write to, causing undefined behaviour. `GetCurrentDirectory()` does not allocate a buffer for the caller: it must be provided.

Change to:

```
char iniFilePath[MAX_PATH]; // or similar.
```

Instead of using [`lstrcat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms647487%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which has *Warning Do not use* message on its reference page, construct the path use a `std::string` instead to avoid potential buffer overruns:

```
const std::string full_file_path(std::string(iniFilePath) + "/" + iniFileName);
```

Note similar issue with `buffer`, as pointed out by [Wimmel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33499/wimmel).

Comment: and after that has been fixed, buffer is also unintialised, which can be solved the same way

Comment: @Wimmel, missed that! Will add to the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in order to get the current directory -

```
int pathLength = GetCurrentDirectory(0, NULL);
std::vector<char> iniFilePath(pathLength);

GetCurrentDirectory(pathLength, iniFilePath.data());
```

Note however that this won't be thread safe as the directory could change from another thread between the two calls but as far as I know few programs change the current directory so it's unlikely to be an issue.

Comment: The path returned will never be longer than MAX_PATH so it's easier (and safer) to just use a fixed-size buffer.

Comment: What about Unicode GetCurrentDirectoryW() ? Won't it return longer paths than MAX_PATH in some specific cases when users managed to create really long paths which actually are supported by NTFS?